# Русская строка в C

Tags: c++, c

Как получается что русские символы умещаются в C строке в кодировке UTF-8 когда каждый русский символ в этой кодировке занимает 2 байта, а ячейка в C строке вмещает только 1 байт?
Почему если выводить эту строку, то она выведется без проблем, а если выводить её посимвольно, то она выводит ошибки?
Ещё если можно, то посоветуйте материалов почитать по этой теме.

```
char a[] = "Строка";
std::cout << a << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как раз поэтому. Русские символы занимают больше одного байта, из-за чего обычный посимвольный вывод не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чудес не бывает - символы, занимающие больше одного байта в `Си` так же занимают больше одного байта. В случае со строкой `char` они лежат в нескольких ячейках (в случае с двухбайтными - первый символ лежит в первых двух, второй - во вторых двух).

Если говорить о `C++`, то для многобайтных символов есть специальный тип `wchar_t`, который имеет размер в 4 байта для `GNU/Linux` и 2 байта для `Windows API`

Аналогом `std::string` для этого типа является `std::wstring`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

---

```
// сперва считаем символ беззнаковым, потом переводим его в целое число
char a[] = "Строка";
std::cout << (int)(unsigned char)a[0] << "; " << (int)(unsigned char)a[1] << std::endl;
```

Выведет `208; 161` (https://ideone.com/FyUdhj)

Согласно вот это (https://unicode-table.com/ru/0421/) таблице, символ `С` в `UTF-8` представляется двумя байтами, как раз `208 161`

Comment: А что вы понимаете под символом Си в таком случае? По сути программа выводит в поток вывода два байта (один символ) и можно сказать забывает про них. Их интерпретирует консоль в зависимости от настроенной кодировки

Comment: Мне до сих пор не понятно как значения -48 и -95 которые лежат в первых двух ячейках образуют русский символ "C".

Comment: Каждый символ в `Си` - это всего лишь набор бит. Русский символ занимает два байта и поэтому он внутри представлен как два однобайтовых `char`-а. При этом никто не гарантирует, что они будут являться реальными читаемыми символами, если выводить их по одному

Comment: Если перевести первые 2 ячейки в int, то получаться символы -48 и -95,  они как-то складываются для вывода первой русской буквы "C"? Потому-что в UTF-8 десятичное значение русского символа "C" равно 1057, это мой последний вопрос который мне не понятен.

Comment: @nammidd первый байт '\xd0' (-48 или 208) это не корректный utf-8 символ. Так как корректный однобайтовый символ имеет диапазон 0-127. Значит это многобайтовый символ. Тогда консоль ожидает следующего байта. Следующий байт  '\xa1', а '\xd0\xa1' корректно преобразуется к символу 'С'.

Comment: @nammidd, дополнил ответ

Comment: @nammidd символ **!=** байт. Это независимо от языка программирования.

Answer (score 3):

Ячейка в С-строке вмещает, конечно, один байт, но каждый символ в таком случае будет занимать в ней два места. И длина всей строки -- 12

```
char a[] = "Строка";
std::cout << a << ' ' << strlen(a) << std::endl; // Строка 12
```

Например, если вывести из этой строки по два символа, то выведутся правильные символы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    std::cout << a[2*i] << a[2*i+1] << std::endl;
```

utf-8 -- мультибайтовая кодировка (разные символы могут занимать разное [количество байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#.D0.94.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B_Unicode)). В том числе кириллические символы будут занимать два байта. При инициализации строки каждый по два байта и займёт.
Следующие две конструкции с точки зрения языка эквивалентны:

```
char a[] = "\xd0\xa1\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0";
char a[] = "Строка";
```

Comment: Каким образом он в ней занимает 2 места?

Comment: @nammidd, из-за использования в вашем файле исходных кодов кодировки UTF-8. К слову, длина символов в этой кодировке непостоянна и зависит от номера *кодовой точки* конкретного символа. Так как кириллица лежит в диапазоне *больше `0x7f`, но меньше `0x7ff`*, то на каждый символ кириллицы отводится по два байта.

Comment: Дополнительно узнать о UTF-8 можно [из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).